# how can i put an integer and a string into a map at the same time?

Tags: android

I want to add into MySQL and SQLite database strings such as email and an integer value of a string such as `peanut=0`. In my XML file I have switches and when I turn on the switch I want to update this value and make it 1.

I wrote some code and in my method, I am trying to put strings and integers in one map. How can I do that?

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        // Posting params to update url
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("tag", "update");
        params.put("email", email); //
            Map<String, Integer> params2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            params2.put("peanut", peanut1); //
            params2.put("lactose", lactose1); //
            params2.put("w3", w31); //
            params2.put("egg", egg1); //
            params2.put("soy", soy1); //
            params2.put("fish", fish1); //
            params2.put("snail", snail1); //
            params2.put("nuts", nuts1); //
            params2.put("wheat", wheat1); //
            params2.put("strawberry", strawberry1); //
            params2.put("milk", milk1); //
            params2.put("gluten", gluten1); //
params.putAll(params2);


            return params;
        }
```

Comment: can you explain what is the output you need?

Comment: Why do you need 2 param-maps? Seems like the `builder-pattern` might be a cleaner approach: https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/

Answer (score 1):

You can define your map like this

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("string", "string");
map.put("integer", 1);
```

Use,

```
@Override
protected Map<String, Object> getParams() {
    // Posting params to update url
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("tag", "update");
        params.put("email", email); //
        params.put("peanut", peanut1); //
        params.put("lactose", lactose1); //
        params.put("w3", w31); //
        params.put("egg", egg1); //
        params.put("soy", soy1); //
        params.put("fish", fish1); //
        params.put("snail", snail1); //
        params.put("nuts", nuts1); //
        params.put("wheat", wheat1); //
        params.put("strawberry", strawberry1); //
        params.put("milk", milk1); //
        params.put("gluten", gluten1); //


   return params;

}
```

Comment: thank you...seems right but i have another little problem. In return says  incompatible types. Required String, String and Found String,Object. ANd when i correct the method to protected Map<String, Object> getParams() says "attempting to use incompatible return type"

Comment: This solution might work, but keep in mind that you lose the type information. So when you get elements from the map, you need to use `instanceof` in order to avoid a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @DebbieMp I think you need to change your return type and receiving variable type as `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @DebbieMp as Jyoti said. you need to change return type as Map<String, Object>

Comment: @JyotiJK i have edited my comment and said that when i change the return type shows error "attempting to use incompatible return type"